# Which kind of investment seems feasible to have more cashflow every week or month?

Tags: investing, stocks, stock-analysis

My plan is to make close to $2000 a month/$500 a week through investments. For that, I can risk up to $2000 to start with. The following come in to my mind, even if nothing is for sure.

1) If I invest $2000 in stocks whose share is around $10 (though i can go between $8-$20 if it is going help me achieve what I wanted), i.e 200 shares.

So if those shares go up at least $1 in 2 days i.e I can make $200 in 2 days and at least $400 in a week (by selling them and then again buy other stocks with lower price or the same stock when it gets down).  I was watching GRPN, and the stock was going up and down b/n 10-14 in a week.

I know there is a risk associated with it, but I am willing to learn and take the risks as well. I know it won't be something easy like that, but is that a bad idea?

Comment: What if the shares go down instead of up? You might want to read up a little to see what typical returns from stock are. If you have a sure-fire way of making $2000 a month with an investment of $2000, people will be beating a path to your door asking for investment advice.

Comment: @DilipSarwate .. You are right. It may go down instead but, that is why I said I will take the risk.

Comment: Whenever I invested with that enthusiasm I lost heavily :(

Comment: does putting/pulling money from stocks have any fees? or holding period?

Comment: @CarlosJaimeC.DeLeon In my case, yeah it has a fee for putting/pulling.

Answer (score 11):

Over the long run, you can expect to do about as well as the market itself. Depending on what time period you view, the stock market has typically provided returns of approximately 10%. Some years it is up, some years it is down. You may think you can get better returns, but [you are mistaken](http://www.figuide.com/why-you-think-you-can-beat-the-stock-market-but-really-cant.html). You may be able to do better over a short time period if you take on vastly more risk, but you won't be able to do so long term.

In order to make $2000/month, then, you will need approximately $240,000 to invest. And even then, you won't make that kind of return reliably. Some months, some years, you'll make more. Other times, you'll lose money.

If anyone tells you they can double your money in a month (which is what you are hoping for), walk away. Because it is either illegal or a scam.

The only way your plan can work is if you are reliably able to predict stocks which will go up by 10% in the next two days. **You cannot do this**. You can't even predict which stocks will go up by 10% in the next year.

Comment: To be clear, if you have $2000 to start investing and want to make $2000/month, the level of risk you are going to have to take is probably that of buying lottery tickets.

Comment: Thank you @Chris .. I understand what you are talking about. & I will re-think what I am doing.

Comment: I don't think 10% on stock market is realistic anytime soon, and 10% over inflation - probably never.

Comment: Chris was talking history, and the 10% is a good number. No one knows what future returns will be, but that's another discussion.

Answer (score 4):

Ignoring the wildly unreasonable goal, I'll answer just the Headline question asked.
It's possible to choose dividend paying stocks so that you receive a dividend check each month. Dividends are typically paid quarterly, so 3 stocks chosen by quality first, but also for their dividend date will do this. To get $2000/mo or $24,000/yr would only take an investment of $600,000 in stocks that are yielding a 4% dividend.

Comment: If a company has 4% dividend and you invest $1000, are you going to get $40 (1000*4/100) quarterly or annually?

Comment: See my math above. The 4% is annual. A bit lower than the 1200% you seek. Sorry.

Comment: Oh, yeah. I should have calculated it myself.

Answer (score 1):

I'll mirror what the others have said in that your expectations for returns are wildly out of line with reality. If you could achieve that with only moderate risk hopefully you can see that you could ladder those returns by re-investing them and become a billionaire in short order. You may have noticed that there are a lot of really financially savvy people who are not billionaires. So the math for your plan falls apart somewhere, obviously.

However, in the spirit of being helpful, and with the caveat that super high returns involve super high risk I'll try and point you in the direction where this is theoretically possible, even if the odds would be better buying lottery tickets. One way to get more leverage from your money than just buying stocks is to buy options. With an options strategy your return/loss will be magnified greatly compared to buying stocks. That is, you can lose or gain a much higher multiplier of your original investment.

That said, I don't advise doing that with any money that you can't afford to lose every penny of, because you likely will.